# Android Java Карты

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно сделать что-то типа running tracker app:
Програма определяет текущее местоположение, мы запускаем таймер и на карте будет отрисован наш маршрут бега. Как работать с картами и этой прорисовкой в android на java?
С чего вообще стоит начать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Подключите библиотеки поставщика карт. Например Huawei/Yandex/google
2. Опционально, для удобства подключите библиотеки для удобного получения обновлений местоположения.
3. При изменении координат девайса - рисуйте на карте, средствами API карты, линию от предыдущей точки до текущей.

Вот и всё.